# se puede comparar los decibeles de dos audios en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito realizar una pagina web con situaciones, donde cada situación tiene dos caminos, el cual se determina captando el audio de el camino A y B, y dependiendo de cual sea mas intenso elegir ese camino, hice un sintetizador para visualizar la captacion de mi microfono y pude lograrlo, pero queria saber si habia manera de captar la frecuencia mas alta y compararla con otro audio

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#mp3_player{ width:500px; height:60px; background:#000; padding:5px; margin:50px auto; }
div#mp3_player > div > audio{  width:500px; background:#000; float:left;  }
div#mp3_player > canvas{ width:500px; height:30px; background:#002D3C; float:left; }
</style>
<script>
// Create a new instance of an audio object and adjust some of its properties
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'track1.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
// Establish all variables that your Analyser will use
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
// Initialize the MP3 player after the page loads all of its HTML into the window
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
function initMp3Player(){
    document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
    context = new webkitAudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance
    analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
    canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); 
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
}
// frameLooper() animates any style of graphics you wish to the audio frequency
// Looping at the default frame rate that the browser provides(approx. 60 FPS)
function frameLooper(){
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF'; // Color of the bars
    bars = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * 3;
        bar_width = 2;
        bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
        //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mp3_player">
  <div id="audio_box"></div>
  <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y que has intentado, cuales son tus errores, tienes alguna estructura ya armada, aca se resuelven dudas con problemas relacionados al desarrollo de software.

Comment: hice un sintetizador donde puedo ver las distintas frecuencias en la cancion, queria saber si habia alguna manera de comparar eso con otro audio captado por microfono